# Get TextView/Layout width according to device.

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am making an application where first i need to get the `TextView` size and then apply it to a `Layout` by adjusting it according to the `TextView`. But the sizes changes device to device...is there any procedure where i could cope up these differences.

Comment: Better if you avoid naive calculations on UI elements. What about using "wrap_content" for your layout's width?

Comment: i need to control the width of my layout according to my textview. bcz i need to put a background to my layout. when i use wrap_content, it does not limits my layout.

Comment: I don't get you... wrap_content surrounds the conained Views to match their size (unless you don't have margins and/or paddings).

Comment: Thnx, got your point. trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Item to be the same from device to device I would place your textview inbetween to empty views in a linearlayout than use the sum-weight and adjust the layout weight to be what you want it to be. and than adjust the layout_height or width (depends on horizontal vs vertical linear layout) to the appropriate amount.  for example a horizontal linear layout you would set layout_width to 0dp, vertical you would set layout_height to 0dp.  here is some example code from an old project

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_new_customer_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/add_customer_button_label"/>

        <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this would make something that looks like

[empty view][Button THAT IS 1/2 of SCREEN CENTERED][empty view]